# Visibility checkboxes in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a resource in ActiveAdmin that contains a index table.

This table has about 15 columns.

Is there an easy way to have some checkboxes (or some other thing) for the user to choose which columns to display, and which to hide?

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky. Use columns names in some table.
for eg : activeadmin_columns

```
 id, model_name, cols_array, user_id
 1, User, ["first_name", "last_name", "email"], 2
```

Now in users.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    index do
        current_user.activeadmin_columns.cols_array.each do |col|
          column :"#{col}"
        end
    end
end
```

This will only show the column which is coming from db.
This is just overview it require more effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use filter function in activeadmin. If you use filter, you can see something you select.**

Comment: That's not my question :)